how to retrieve data sent with Curl in php
I have a php code that sends a request via curl to end-point.php. In end-point.php I try to display the value of the transmitted data but nothing is displayed. Here's my code:
// Prepare subscriber data
$data = array(
    'name' => "John"
);

// Set cURL options
$url = "https://www.example.com/end-point.php";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
));

// Execute cURL request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

// Check if the request was successful
if ($http_code >= 200 && $http_code < 300) {
    echo $response;
} else {
    // Output error message
    echo "Error";
}

And here is the code for the end-point.php file:
echo $_POST['name'];


Do you understand the meaning of 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'?

Try changing Content-Type: multipart/form-data to Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data

Just leave out the Content-Type header. curl will send the correct header automatically.

Did you try to add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); ?

@AbsoluteBeginner that's not good advice, unless there's really genuinely an unsolveable SSL problem. And there's no specific evidence for that so far.

@ADyson It wasn't meant to be a "good advice", but just a tip to find out the issue's cause.

To fix this, you can simply remove the Content-Type header or set it to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which is the default content type for POST requests.
Here's the corrected code for the Curl request:
// Prepare subscriber data
$data = array(
    'name' => "John"
);

// Set cURL options
$url = "https://www.example.com/end-point.php";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data)); // Use http_build_query to encode the data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute cURL request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

// Check if the request was successful
if ($http_code >= 200 && $http_code < 300) {
    echo $response;
} else {
    // Output error message
    echo "Error";
}

And in your end-point.php file, you can access the data using the $_POST superglobal:
echo $_POST['name']; // Should output "John"

